# Using `curve` with a function from a list

Tags: r, list, function, plot, curve

Why does `curve` not seem to work with elements extracted from a list?

Consider two seemingly identical functions, but built differently:

```r
a <- function(value){
  function(x) x + value
}

m <- lapply(1:3, a)
f <- a(1)
all.equal(f, m[[1]])
#[1] TRUE
```

`curve` works for `f`, but not `m[[1]]`:

```r
> curve(m[[1]])
Error in curve(m[[1]]) : 
  'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'
```

But it works if the object is extracted before:

```r
d <- m[[1]]
curve(d)
```

Is there a reason for it?

Comment: It's documented behaviour.  `m[[1]]` is not "The name of a function, or a call or an expression written as a function of x which will evaluate to an object of the same length as x."  It's an expression which evaluates to a function.  `d` is the name of a function.  You can get what you want using `curve(m[[1]](x))` which makes it an expression written as a function of x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`curve()` is a "magic" function that tries to interpret its input as an expression when possible; it doesn't always work.

@user2554330 comments that `curve()` is expecting (from `?curve`):

> The name of a function, or a call or an expression written as a function of `x` which will evaluate to an object of the same length as `x`.

Instead, `m[[1]]` is an **expression that evaluates to a function**. In contrast, `d` is the name of a function. You can get what you want using `curve(m[[1]](x))` which makes the input an expression written as a function of x.

In the code below, R looks at the expression passed to `curve()` and asks whether `is.name(sexpr)` is TRUE. This test passes for `f` but fails for `m[[1]]` (if you want to test it outside of the function context, you need to compare `is.name(quote(f))` and `is.name(quote(m[[1]])`).

Weirdly enough, `plot(m[[1]])` *does* work (it calls `plot.function()`, which calls `curve()` with different arguments internally).

```
sexpr <- substitute(expr)
if (is.name(sexpr)) {
    expr <- call(as.character(sexpr), as.name(xname))
}
else {
    if (!((is.call(sexpr) || is.expression(sexpr)) && xname %in% 
        all.vars(sexpr))) 
        stop(gettextf("'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing '%s'", 
            xname), domain = NA)
    expr <- sexpr
}
```

Comment: A very weird behavior, but a very comprehensive explanation ;) Thanks